# How to use PreAuthorize with async Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-3.0

I have a Spring MVC service which lets me upload a file. It uses `@PreAuthorize` from Spring Security to handle access controls on resources. The controller uses Servlet 3 async servlets by use of a Callable.

```
@PreAuthorize("...")
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Callable<ResponseEntity> upload(final InputStream inputStream)
{
    return new Callable<ResponseEntity>()
    {
        @Override
        public ResponseEntity call() throws Exception
        {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

Somewhere in the service - outside of my code - an exception is being thrown.

```
An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

The exception appears to be thrown by the cglib generated code for my Spring controller. Here is bulk of the stack trace.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:339) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:198) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.testing.upload.controller.RESTService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$66a0c4c9.upload(<generated>) ~[spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:849) [spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:758) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
```

I have updated my web.xml from the instructions at the bottom of [this blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2012/12/17/spring-security-3-2-m1-highlights-servlet-3-api-support/#servlet3-async) about async support in Spring Security 3.2.

Finally, the error does not always happen. It only appears to happen when I try to upload a large file. This makes me think that it does indeed have something to do with trying to make the controller an async controller.

Versions:

- Spring 3.2.4
- Spring Security 3.2
- cglib 3.1
- Java Servlet 3.0
- Java 6
- Jetty 8

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that the security context is unavailable if the upload is happening in a spawned thread. This is because the security context by default is bound to the parent thread and a new child threads won't know about it.

You can try changing the `SecurityContextHolder` strategy to `InheritableThreadLocal` making it available to spawned threads.

You can set this programatically:

```
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL
```

Or in the Spring XML config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass"
        value="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setStrategyName"/>
    <property name="arguments"><list><value>MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL</value></list></property>
</bean>
```

Or you can set an system property when you start your app:

```
-Dspring.security.strategy=MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. I am seeing the same error.

Comment: Which one of the three mechanisms of setting the strategy did you use?

Comment: I tried both the XML and the programatic approaches. For the programatic approach, I put the call in the constructor to my Spring MVC controller's constructor.